# Executing s. procedure from linked server, filling table

Tags: sql-server, transactions, linked-server

OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "server1" returned message "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.".
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp2, Line 12
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "server1" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

and procedure is simple

```
insert into #tmp2 exec sp2 @d1, @d2, 0
```

without insert, it's working, like `exec sp2 @d1, @d2, 0`

I don't have transaction anywhere.

What can be problem?

Comment: had a similar issue before can you try the answer that I was given: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718473/slow-performance-in-linked-server-query

Answer (score 0):

Please start MSDTC Service on Database server.

Answer (score 0):

Also set,

'remote proc transaction promotion' property to 'false'

e.g.sp_serveroption <>,'remote proc transaction promotion',false